# Qual è il senso di questo utilizzo del verbo "usare"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nella prefazione a *Nostro lunedí* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Mi dispiace che siano andati a finire cosí. Erano dei dilettanti magnifici: erano tutti interessanti ed inutili: solo che si divertivano con ingegnosi giocattoli e fiori di carta e graziose barchette, nient’altro: ed io penso che la vita dovrebbe avere sufficiente cavalleria ed anche spirito per **usare** loro almeno qualche riguardo.

Tra le tantissime accezioni del verbo "usare" che si trovano nei dizionari, non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'uso che si fa in questo passaggio. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: È questa parte della voce del Treccani: “In unione con termini astratti, adoperare nel proprio comportamento, nel proprio agire: u. prudenza, cautela; u. astuzia; u. attenzione; per estens., con un compl. di termine, fare qualcosa a vantaggio o a svantaggio di uno: usatemi la carità di aiutarmi; usatemi questa cortesia; m’hanno usato mille premure; u. violenza a una donna, violentarla; u. violenza a sé stessi, fig., costringersi a fare qualcosa contro il proprio interesse, o controllare con forza i proprî istinti.”

Comment: @DaG, scrivi una risposta

Comment: Sono d'accordo con abarisone, @DaG: per me questo va benissimo come risposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

È un'accezione specifica del verbo “usare” che si applica appunto a comportamenti e simili, e si può costruire con un complemento di termine per indicare verso chi si “usa” quell'atteggiamento. Per citare [la voce “usare” del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/usare):

> In unione con termini astratti, adoperare nel proprio comportamento, nel proprio agire: *u. prudenza, cautela*; *u. astuzia*; *u. attenzione*; per estens., con un compl. di termine, fare qualcosa a vantaggio o a svantaggio di uno: *usatemi la carità di aiutarmi*; *usatemi questa cortesia*; *m’hanno usato mille premure*; *u. violenza a una donna*, violentarla; *u. violenza a sé stessi*, fig., costringersi a fare qualcosa contro il proprio interesse, o controllare con forza i proprî istinti.

Comment: Se "loro" in questa frase è complemento di termine, si potrebbe anche dire "usar**gli** almeno qualche riguardo"? (non mi sembra tanto bello, però).

Comment: @Charo: L'uso di "gli" per il  plurale in genere è ormai accettato, ma stonerebbe decisamente in uno stile alto e sorvegliato come quello di D'Arzo.